# R dynamic row insert loop performance

Tags: r

In cleaning up a dirty data set, my final step is to build out a set of dummy rows with a set number of pipe delimiters for each "type" of row (uptopipe) for each record_numb. I've read quite a bit on this and have gotten this to work, but am looking to see if any of you experts have a more efficient processing method for me to try.

This table shows how many dummy rows I need to make of each type for each record:

```
uptopipe <- c("A","B","C")
empty_rows_needed <- c(4,3,2)
pipes <- c('|||||','||','|||||||')
record_numb <- c(1,1,1)
rows_to_make <- data.frame(record_numb, uptopipe, empty_rows_needed, pipes)
rows_to_make$row_numb <- rownames(rows_to_make)

record_numb          uptopipe   empty_rows_needed pipes     row_numb
1                    A          4                 |||||     1
1                    B          3                 ||        2
1                    C          2                 |||||||   3
```

For my example I will only show 1 record_numb, but I'll need to loop through several record_numb values. 
I have a separate table that has all of my records which I'll need to append:

```
record_numb <-  c(1,1,1)
uptopipe   <-  c("A","A","B")
V1     <-    c("Alah|||||","Alah|||||","Blah||")
my_data <- data.frame(record_numb , uptopipe, V1)

 record_numb  uptopipe   V1
           1         A   Alah|||||
           1         A   Alah|||||
           1         B   Blah||
```

My goal here is to make it so each record_number has the same number of A, B, and C rows. The rows I need to insert should just have the pipes for the blank rows I create. 
"A" has 2 records and needs 4 dummies
"B" has 1 records and needs 3 dummies
"C" has 0 records and needs 2 dummies

The dummy output should look like this:

```
record_numb     uptopipe    V1
          1            A    |||||
          1            A    |||||
          1            A    |||||
          1            A    |||||
          1            B    ||
          1            B    ||
          1            B    ||
          1            C    |||||||
          1            C    |||||||
```

My approach has been to create a separate data frame (my_new_rows) with all the dummy records, then to rbind that to the existing good records in a separate data frame. I have tried 4 methods to create the dummies, all of which work, but the performance is horrible. Here is what I've tried:

Method 1:

```
  #make dataframe shell
  my_new_rows <- data.frame(record_numb=integer(), uptopipe=character(), V1=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(rows_to_make)) {
        for (j in 1:subset(rows_to_make,row_numb==i)$empty_rows_needed){
          my_new_rows <- rbind(my_new_rows,data.frame(record_numb=subset(rows_to_make,record_numb==i)$record_numb,
                                                  uptopipe=subset(rows_to_make,record_numb==i)$uptopipe,
                                                  V1=subset(rows_to_make,record_numb==i)$pipes
                                         ))
    }
  }
```

Method 2 - use variables and append

```
  my_new_rows <- data.frame(record_numb=integer(), uptopipe=character(), V1=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


  rec_num_1 = NULL
  u2p1      = NULL
  V1_1      = NULL

  for (i in 1:nrow(rows_to_make)) {
    for (j in 1:subset(rows_to_make,row_numb==i)$empty_rows_needed){
  rec_num_1 = append(rec_num_1,subset(rows_to_make,row_numb==i)$record_numb)
  u2p1      = append(u2p1,     as.character(subset(rows_to_make,row_numb==i)$uptopipe))
  V1_1      = append(V1_1,     as.character(subset(rows_to_make,row_numb==i)$pipes))
  }}   #takes a while -- 30 mins?
  my_new_rows <- data.frame(rec_num_1,u2p1,V1_1)
```

I've tried a couple other methods using sqldf/sprintf, but that is even slower than these.

I am creating roughly 120k dummy records and it is taking nearly an hour with each of these approaches.

Can somebody suggest a more efficient approach to generate the dummy records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rep` to replicate the sequence of rows with the third column and then use that index to expand the dataset

```
df1 <- rows_to_make[rep(1:nrow(rows_to_make), rows_to_make[,3]),][c(1,2,4)]
row.names(df1) <- NULL
df1
```

Comment: Well, you just chopped off an hour of processing time for me, that runs instantly. Thank you so much!